# Create loop and save output in .txt or .fasta file

Tags: loops, design-patterns, save, sequence

I have an data set with 7754 obs. and 5 variables

```
name    protein     mutation_CDS    mutation_nonCDS     seq
B*07    02                01               01           ATGCTGGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCGTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTCGG
B*07    02                01               48           ATGCTGGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCGTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTCGG
...
B*18    153               NA               NA           ATGCGGGTCACGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTGGG
B*18    155               NA               NA           ATGCGGGTCACGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTGGG
...
```

Within the "name" variable I have 36 different names with different numbers of rows having this name
"B*07" "B*08" "B*13" "B*14" "B*15" "B*18" "B*27" "B*35" "B*37" "B*38" "B*39" "B*40" "B*41" "B*42" "B*44" "B*45" "B*46" "B*47" "B*48" "B*49" "B*50" "B*51" "B*52" "B*53" "B*54" "B*55" "B*56" "B*57" "B*58" "B*59" "B*67" "B*73" "B*78" "B*81" "B*82" "B*83"

My idea was, to create a loop within R in which I take the whole data set with its 7754 obs., look for the unique name ("B*07") and store all rows (including columns) having this name and stored it in a new data set with the lable "B07" OR directly create a .txt (or .fasta) file.

I would end up with separate files, for example a file called B07 containing only the B*07 information (620 obs. and 5 variables)

```
name    protein     mutation_CDS    mutation_nonCDS     seq
B*07    02                01              01            ATGCTGGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCGTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTCGG
B*07    02                01              48            ATGCTGGTCATGGCGCCCCGAACCGTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTCGG
```

and a file called B08 containing only the B*08 information (X obs. and 5 variables)

```
B*18    153     NA      NA          ATGCGGGTCACGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTGGG
B*18    155     NA      NA          ATGCGGGTCACGGCGCCCCGAACCCTCCTCCTGCTGCTCTGGG
```

In simple words, I want to split the 7754 observations in their parts referring to a certain name pattern

"B*07"  620 of 7754

"B*08"  X   of 7754

"B*13"  X   of 7754

etc.

does anyone have an Idea how to do that?